# How to use a method in other classes?

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, code-reuse

I have a method that I want to use in almost all the classes within a same c# project.

```
public void Log(String line)
{
   var file = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory)+ "Logs.txt";

   StreamWriter logfile = new StreamWriter(file, true);

   // Write to the file:
   logfile.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
   logfile.WriteLine(line);
   logfile.WriteLine();

   // Close the stream:
   logfile.Close();
}
```

What is the approach to reuse this method in other classes of the project?

Comment: why don't you use log4net for any else log tool rather than managing by yourself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use it in **all** classes, then make it `static`.

You could have a `static` `LogHelper` class to better organise it, like:

```
public static class LogHelper
{
    public static void Log(String line)
    {
        var file = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory)+ "Logs.txt";

        StreamWriter logfile = new StreamWriter(file, true);

        // Write to the file:
        logfile.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        logfile.WriteLine(line);
        logfile.WriteLine();

        // Close the stream:
        logfile.Close();
    }
}
```

Then call it by doing `LogHelper.Log(line)`

Comment: I've wanted to post answer with links to Aspect-Oriented programming, using PostSharp for compile time aspects of some IoC container interceptors for dynamic aspects. But it seems that all he needs, is a `static` keyword...

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Yeah whilst IOC containers are **very useful**, it'd be sledgehammer to crack a nut in this instance.

Answer (score 4):

You can make a static class and put this function in that class.

```
public static MyStaticClass
{
    public static void Log(String line)
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Now you can call it elsewhere. (No need to instantiate because it's a static class)

```
MyStaticClass.Log("somestring");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Extrension method` in statis class

Sample on string extension

```
public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static int YourMethod(this String str)
        {
        }
    }
```

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx